# Getting Tango's camera stream data

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm trying to get the Tango's camera stream in order to combine an homemade AR Kit to Tango.

I'm stuck at a point where everything works as intended in Tango's editor emulation, but not in the app pushed to the tablet.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
YUVTexture yuvTexture = m_tangoApplication.GetVideoOverlayTextureYUV();
Texture2D yTexture = yuvTexture.m_videoOverlayTextureY;
// m_videoOverlayTextureCr is not used by Tango yet for some reason
Texture2D uvTexture = yuvTexture.m_videoOverlayTextureCb;

// convert from YV12 to RGB
for (int i = 0; i < yTexture.height; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < yTexture.width; ++j)
    {
        Color yPixel = yTexture.GetPixel(j, i);
        Color uvPixel = uvTexture.GetPixel(j, i);

        m_texture.SetPixel(4 * j + 0, yTexture.height - i - 1, YUV2Color(yPixel.r, uvPixel.r, uvPixel.g));
        m_texture.SetPixel(4 * j + 1, yTexture.height - i - 1, YUV2Color(yPixel.g, uvPixel.r, uvPixel.g));
        m_texture.SetPixel(4 * j + 2, yTexture.height - i - 1, YUV2Color(yPixel.b, uvPixel.b, uvPixel.a));
        m_texture.SetPixel(4 * j + 3, yTexture.height - i - 1, YUV2Color(yPixel.a, uvPixel.b, uvPixel.a));
    }
}
```

YUV2Color (extracted from Tango's YUV2RGB Shader):

```
public static Color YUV2Color(float y_value, float u_value, float v_value)
{
    float r = y_value + 1.370705f * (v_value - 0.5f);
    float g = y_value - 0.698001f * (v_value - 0.5f) - (0.337633f * (u_value - 0.5f));
    float b = y_value + 1.732446f * (u_value - 0.5f);

    return new Color(r, g, b, 1f);
}
```

Did someone already solved this problem? I've seen a lot of post related to it when the *ITangoVideoOverlay* was mostly used, but nothing with the current *IExperimentalTangoVideoOverlay*

I've experimented a lot of things, so far it has been the closest I got to what I expected ... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Texture ID method to get the YUV texture color, this is not very common to do. A easier path would be using the `Raw Byte` buffer method to get color camera image, to do that:

1. On `TangoManager` prefab, enable video overlay, and select `Raw Byte` method from the drop down box.
2. Register to [ITangoVideoOverlay](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/interface/i-tango-video-overlay) interface.
3. Convert the image buffer data from YUV to RGB, this part is exactly like the YUV2Color function, but use data from [TangoImageData.data](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/tango-unity-image-data#class_tango_1_1_tango_unity_image_data_1a0cec79b5bfb41f2f44e1533b5ff04237)