# How can I get RGB or YUV data in Google Project Tango?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-project-tango

I'm trying to use Google Project Tango to detect the color of camera-specific coordinates, because I want to do something by measuring depth values ​​in coordinates with a certain color.

However, I don't know how to access the color values ​​of camera frames. How can  do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access color data with ITangoVideoOverlay.
Check this question and answer: [Saving Tango camera data as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360382/saving-tango-camera-data-as-an-image/45365934#45365934)
There is an explanation for Unity, but it shouldn't be a problem to change it for Android.